# How to insert the first letter in uppercase

Tags: php, functions, categories

short question, I have a variable concatenated with a get_the_title and get_the_category, and I need the get_the_category to show the first letter in capital letters.

```
 <?php echo get_the_title().' - '.get_post_type( get_the_ID() ) ; ?>
```

Anyone have an idea?

Thank-

Comment: [ucfirst](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php)

Comment: @Rup ou, you're right, I focused on just one wordpress function or something like that.
Thank you

Comment: You can just use CSS to text-transform:capitalize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the job

```
<?php echo ucfirst(get_the_title()) .' - '.get_post_type( get_the_ID() ) ;?>
```